# How can I install Android SDK with antivirus turned on?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to install SDK but I'm having no luck.

First of all, I kept getting the following error:

> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml,
>   reason: dl-ssl.google.co.uk

I therefore closed that window down and went into Settings to tick the box "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://

But then I got a very similar error which complained about the http:// URL

I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the fact that I have McAfee installed on my PC. The problem is, this is a work PC and I can't disable the antivirus. Is there an alternative method of installing sdk on my PC?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are on win if you have mcafee on your computer. so try launch SDK Manager.exe in the root of the sdk directory to download sdk components. you dont need to do this from eclipse. for further information, see [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: What about downloading and installing neccessary SDK components on another pc (with turned off AV) and copy it over to your workstation?